# put output in the next pipe

Tags: linux, bash

I want to move the output of the command:

```
ls -1 /${TMP_DIR}/*0000000221*.dbf | xargs | sed 's/ /,/g'
```

In the end of a command that come after it, like that:

```
ls -1 /${TMP_DIR}/*0000000221*.dbf | xargs | sed 's/ /,/g' | impdp sim/sim files=$1
```

For example:

execute `ls -1 /${TMP_DIR}/*0000000221*.dbf | xargs | sed 's/ /,/g'` will give me:

`/tmp/a_0000000221.dbf,/tmp/a_00000002212.dbf,/tmp/b_0000000221.dbf`

So I want the final command will look like:

```
impdp sim/sim files=/tmp/a_0000000221.dbf,/tmp/a_00000002212.dbf,/tmp/b_0000000221.dbf
```

EDIT:
Sorry I didnt write this from the beginning - I've variable in the command `${TMP_DIR}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ls` is a bit redundant if you just want to get the file names.
You can get the shell to glob those and then use printf to put them one per line.

To separate those items with ',' rather than '\n', you can use `paste`

Finally, putting all that within $() will execute that in a subshell,
and output the result for the command in the current shell.

```
impdp sim/sim files=$(printf '%s\n' /${TMP_DIR}/*0000000221*.dbf | paste -d, -s)
```

Comment: Can you explain the `paste -d, -s` and why there is `\n` ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need that many pipes. You can use it like this:

```
printf "impdp sim/sim files=" && printf "%s," /tmp/*0000000221*.dbf
impdp sim/sim files=/tmp/a_0000000221.dbf,/tmp/a_00000002212.dbf,/tmp/b_0000000221.dbf,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use globbing, an array and `IFS` to construct the parameter string:

```
$ ls -1
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt

$ echo impdp sim/sim files="$(a=(*.txt);IFS=',';echo "${a[*]}")"
impdp sim/sim files=1.txt,2.txt,3.txt
```

Obviously this will break on filenames with spaces or newlines.

To run, just remove the `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try other order of commands:

```
impdp sim/sim files=$(ls -1 /tmp/*0000000221*.dbf | xargs | sed 's/ /,/g')
```

Comment: Will it work with inner variable? (e.g `${TMP_DIR}`)

Comment: Why not?, you can enclose within $() any command as if you were in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

(all solutions including mine assumes your filenames do not contain spaces)
sed is a little overkill, you can use tr and avoid xargs too:

```
impdp sim/sim files=$(ls /tmp/*0000000221*.dbf | tr "\n" ",")
```